# Apache Pig's explain-function

Tags: java, apache-pig

I'm trying to understand Pig's `explain`-function ([link](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.14.0/test.html#explain)).

Suppose the following example:

```
A = load 'numbers' using PigStorage(',') as (name, age);
explain A;
```

Which gives me:

```
#-----------------------------------------------
# New Logical Plan:
#-----------------------------------------------
A: (Name: LOStore Schema: name#5:bytearray,age#6:bytearray)
|
|---A: (Name: LOLoad Schema: name#5:bytearray,age#6:bytearray)RequiredFields:[0, 1]
#-----------------------------------------------
# Physical Plan:
#-----------------------------------------------
A: Store(fakefile:org.apache.pig.builtin.PigStorage) - scope-1
|
|---A: Load(file:///...pig-0.14.0/numbers:PigStorage(',')) - scope-0

2014-12-07 15:07:10,596 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MRCompiler - File concatenation threshold: 100 optimistic? false
2014-12-07 15:07:10,609 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MultiQueryOptimizer - MR plan size before optimization: 1
2014-12-07 15:07:10,610 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MultiQueryOptimizer - MR plan size after optimization: 1
#--------------------------------------------------
# Map Reduce Plan                                  
#--------------------------------------------------
MapReduce node scope-2
Map Plan
A: Store(fakefile:org.apache.pig.builtin.PigStorage) - scope-1
|
|---A: Load(file:///.../pig-0.14.0/numbers:PigStorage(',')) - scope-0--------
Global sort: false
----------------
```

What can I see here? I find the output rather confusing.

Comment: http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1234000001811/ch07.html#describe

Answer (score 0):

It tells you the steps pig takes. In your case it explain how the alias A is populated by loading the data and since you are not doing anything with it yet is goes into "fakefile". It describes both the flow and how it breaks into map/reduces

As you probably saw for yourself it gets real messy really fast. You may want to take a look at [Lipstick](https://github.com/Netflix/Lipstick) from Netflix for something that is more approachable